# How to show just private posts in loop

Tags: loop, private

I have a section in my website where i want to display just the private posts for logged in users, but the loop returns all posts (private and publish), is it possible to change this? I have the next code in my loop:

```
global $listingsearch, $listing_query, $wp_query;

$view = listingpress_get_listing_search_view();
$desktop_view = $view['d'];
```

And this

```
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
```

And this

```
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
                $wp_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to filter the main WordPress query using the `pre_get_posts` [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). This code will get you started:

```
function show_only_private_post_for_logged_in_users( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'private' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_only_private_post_for_logged_in_users' );
```

It will only affect the main query and not on the WordPress admin side.

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to alter the main loop and you're looking for more of a widget/section I would throw something similar to the code below in functions.php:

```
function render_private_posts(){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $private_post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'private',
            'posts_per_page'=> 5
        );

        $private_posts = new WP_Query( $private_post_args );

        $private_post_output = NULL;
        if ( $private_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $private_post_output = '<ul>';

            while ( $private_posts->have_posts() ) {
                $private_posts->the_post();
                $private_post_output .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
            }

            $private_post_output .= '</ul>';
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $private_post_output;

    }

    return false;

}
```

You would then use `echo render_private_posts();` where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to get posts in a loop and get their ids, and pass it in another loop inside the first loop and simple just put this function

```
<?php
    if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'private' ) {
    // do something here
    }
?>
```

and this will return posts with visibility status private.
look at this link for better understanding
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status

hope this helps